# flutter-modular how to use routing for only change part of the widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

new to flutter:

Hi, i am using flutter modular to do the flutter navigation 3.0.

For the flutter modular, how do i render only part of the widget when the route is changed?
As it seems that for the below example which from the package document is only one Widget screen for one route, however, i want the const navigation bar, only change the content of each route so that we don't need coding navigation bar in every scree.

route for each screen:

```dart
// app_module.dart
class AppModule extends Module {

  // Provide all the routes for your module
  @override
  final List<ModularRoute>  routes = [
      ChildRoute('/', child: (_, __) => HomePage()),
      ChildRoute('/login', child: (_, __) => LoginPage()),
  ];
}
```

push for the screen:

```dart
Modular.to.navigate('/login');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using your "partial widget" you should use RouterOutlet();
But in your ChildRoute() you may want to change transition settings:

```
ChildRoute('/', child: (_, __) => HomePage(), transition: TransitionType.noTransition)
```